# Origin returns to the standard position without saving the changes

Tags: mesh, origin

By moving the origin in the mesh to the center of the model, it draws a dotted line and the setting is not applied. Can you find out why it is so ? Everything has always been OK, but now I'm faced with such a problem.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Are there any other objects in the scene?

Comment: Yes, there is, but each has its own origin and everything is OK. And with these problems @Zoukeau

Comment: @Zoukeau https://i.imgur.com/BolBmH6.png here is another model from the same scene and its center is where I need it, the same mesh draws a damn dotted line

Comment: I'm guessing it might be parented to a hidden object [like so?](https://i.imgur.com/geQhuvX.png) If this is the case you can clear the parent by pressing Alt+P .